# Cannot import CSV to dbase via Table_to_Table in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, import, error-999999

I have a CSV file with greater than 5 million records. When I imported it to dbase via the Table_to_Table function in ArcMap, it raised ERROR(99999). As a result, only 2 million or so records were imported...

Comment: Fist thing I would do is find out _exactly_ how many records _did_ import, then closely examine the _next_ record in the CSV file to see if there is anything odd there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing your particular dataset, I can't say for sure what the issue might be, but I know I had a similar issue working with some smaller CSV files where it got part way through the CSV and then quit with an error.  What I finally determined was that in one of the fields/columns most of the values were a single numeric value 1 - 9, but I found out that about half way through the CSV there was a record that had A in that field.  So, when ArcGIS Desktop tried reading the CSV it read it and presumed from the first ? number of records that that field was a numeric field, so then when it got to the record with an A in that field it gave the error and quit.  Instead, I had to set up a schema.ini file (in the same folder as the csv file) per the instructions available **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000)** (scroll to the section at the bottom of the page) and it ended up working.

Don't know if that's the problem you're having, but it was the issue with mine, so... hope it helps.